# Json Php / MySql outputting

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a php page as below:

```
$sql = "select code as ref, size from product";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $test[] = $rs;
    }

$output['data'][] = $test;

echo json_encode( $output );
```

This ouputs the following:

```
{"data":[[{"ref":"ABC","size":"Large"},{"ref":"123","size":"Medium"}]]}
```

I need to modify the php, so that I can prefix some characters before the ref value so eg:

ref: ABC should be M-ABC

and

ref: 123 should be M-123

Finally I would also like to add an additional item to the array such as description and this will have a fixed description such as "This product is available in Large" (The value is based on the size).

Thanks

Comment: why not just modify the $output array , and then encode it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rs['ref'] = "M-$rs[ref]";
    $rs['description'] = "This product is available in $rs[size]";
    $test[] = $rs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have known this but such a long time since I did any dev work. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than modify the PHP and have to change your values in a loop, a more unconventional but tidier approach is to modify your SQL and do the string prefixing there:

```
// Changed to a HEREDOC string for readability
$sql =<<<SQL 
  select CONCAT('M-', code) as ref,
   size,
   CASE
    WHEN (size = 'large') THEN 'this product is available in large'
    WHEN (size = 'small') THEN 'this product is available in small'
    WHEN (size = 'someotherone') THEN 'this product...etc.etc.'
   END AS size_description
  from product;
SQL;
```

Now this requires no further post-processing in PHP once you've fetched the records.  You can hand the array from your fetch loop directly to `json_encode()`

Comment: Depends. If you're ever going to localize your app, producing end-user output in SQL is not really an option.

Comment: Thanks Michael but deceze is correct better to do this in php.